# Anti-XML scala hides xml attribute

Tags: xml, scala, namespaces, anti-xml

Anti-xml will be the successor xml library in Scala. But I have found something that quirks.

**Input**

```
package com.twitter.sample
import com.codecommit.antixml._

object ReadingNamespaceXml extends Application{

  val xml = <tra:route xmlns:tra="trace">
              <spo:id xmlnls:spo="sport">23232322</spo:id>
              <tra:service ref="go" xsi:type="ref:manualService" xmlns:ref="ServiceRef"/>
            </tra:route>.convert

  val route =  xml \ "route"
  Console println route.unselect
}
```

**Output:**

```
  <tra:route>
  <spo:id xmlnls:spo="sport">23232322</spo:id>
  <tra:service xsi:type="ref:manualService" ref="go"/>
  </tra:route>
```

So, the input xml and the output are not the same. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is just that this is a bug.

Fortunately there's an easy fix. I don't know the full story on Anti-XML, but Daniel Spiewak no longer seems to be maintaining it—[his repo](https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml) hasn't been touched in years and is still on Scala 2.9.1. There is however [a fork](https://github.com/arktekk/anti-xml) (by a company called Arktekk) that fixes this bug, has builds for 2.10, etc. It's also [available from Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/no.arktekk/anti-xml_2.10). I know nothing about Arktekk, but I've been happily using this fork for a while.

To prove that it works, here's a reduced example using the old 0.3 release:

```
scala> import com.codecommit.antixml._
import com.codecommit.antixml._

scala> <foo ref="bar" xmlns:ref="baz"/>.convert
res0: com.codecommit.antixml.Elem = <foo ref="bar"/>
```

And now with Arktekk's 0.5.1:

```
scala> import com.codecommit.antixml._
import com.codecommit.antixml._

scala> <foo ref="bar" xmlns:ref="baz"/>.convert
res0: com.codecommit.antixml.Elem = <foo xmlns:ref="baz" ref="bar"/>
```

Which is what you'd expect.